# For loop in python and exporting to excel

Tags: excel, pandas, pandas.excelwriter

I am pulling info from a table ('tr') online. 
I have a loop function that cycles through the table for the info i am looking for. 
my output is good and it is exact what i want. However, when I export to excel using panda, instead of placing all my data on the same sheet (ideally, per row), it is creating different sheets for each time it executes each loop (each variable).

How do i offset/get all my info in a table or an array of sort?

ps. I am new (1 month) to python... so please elaborate thank you.

I have tried moving around my dataframe and writer but nothing seems to work.\
I also tried offsetting my startrow but i am not sure if i did it correctly, but whatever i did in my attempt never worked.
I have narrowed down the issue and I believe it has to do with this line here:

```
df2.to_excel(writer,sheet_name='test',startrow=n, index=False)  
df2=pd.DataFrame({"Company":[Company],"Revenue":[revenue],"Cash":[total_cash]}) #Headers
writer=pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx',engine='openpyxl', mode='a')
df2.to_excel(writer,sheet_name='test',startrow=n, index=False) 
writer.save()
```

Comment: Why are you using a for loop to write the data to excel? you an directly do `df.to_excel('output.xlsx', sheet_name='test')`

Comment: One more thought. Try entering the filename inside the `df.to_excel`

Comment: @SH-SF, the for loop is to pull the company’s name from an another excel sheet and then base on the name go to the web and grab the necessary information. So correct me if I am incorrect but isn’t a for loop necessary because otherwise it doesn’t work. As for the file name, the “writer” like with the file name “output.xlsx” already exist so again would combining it with “df.to_excel” would really make a difference?